# How to pass a formula as a parameter to lm in sapply?

Tags: r, function, subset, lm

It seems that `lm` won't take formula as a parameter when it is within a `sapply`.

Just `lm`

While `lm` alone accepts formula parameter `FO` well,

```
summary(lm(y ~ x, df1, df1[["z"]] == 1, df1[["w"]]))$coef[1, ]
summary(lm(FO, data, data[[st]] == st1, data[[ws]]))$coef[1, ]
```

`lm` in `sapply`

the same within a `sapply`

```
sapply(unique(df1$z), function(s) 
  summary(lm(y ~ x, df1, df1[["z"]] == s, df1[[ws]]))$coef[1, ])
sapply(unique(data[[st]]), function(s) 
  summary(lm(FO, data, data[[st]] == s, data[[ws]]))$coef[1, ])
```

causes the error:

```
 Error in eval(substitute(subset), data, env) : object 's' not found
```

When putting everything as parameter but formula `FO` it's still working:

```
sapply(unique(data[[st]]), function(s) 
  summary(lm(y ~ x, data, data[[st]] == s, data[[ws]]))$coef[1, ])
```

`lm` in `for` loop

All parameters work within a `for` loop:

```
m <- matrix(NA, 4, length(unique(data[[st]])))
for (s in unique(data[[st]])) {
  m[, s] <- summary(lm(FO, data, data[[st]] == s, data[[ws]]))$coef[1, ]
}
m
#           [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
# [1,] 1.6269038 -0.1404174 -0.010338774
# [2,] 0.9042738  0.4577001  1.858138516
# [3,] 1.7991275 -0.3067890 -0.005564049
# [4,] 0.3229600  0.8104951  0.996457853
```

---

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(x = c(1.37095844714667, -0.564698171396089, 0.363128411337339, 
0.63286260496104, 0.404268323140999, -0.106124516091484, 1.51152199743894, 
-0.0946590384130976, 2.01842371387704), y = c(1.30824434809425, 
0.740171482827397, 2.64977380403845, -0.755998096151299, 0.125479556323628, 
-0.239445852485142, 2.14747239550901, -0.37891195982917, -0.638031707027734
), z = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), w = c(0.7, 0.8, 
1.2, 0.9, 1.3, 1.2, 0.8, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

FO <- y ~ x; data <- df1; st <- "z"; ws <- "w"; st1 <- 1
```

---

`sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Switzerland.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Switzerland.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Switzerland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                       
[5] LC_TIME=German_Switzerland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0 tools_3.6.0    yaj_0.0.0.9044 packrat_0.5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a hint from *@David* from R-help to try using `do.call` I could figure it out. The solution is:

```
sapply(unique(data[[st]]), function(s)
  summary(do.call("lm", list(FO, data, data[[st]] == s, 
                             data[[ws]])))$coef[1, ])
#                 [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
# Estimate   1.6269038 -0.1404174 -0.010338774
# Std. Error 0.9042738  0.4577001  1.858138516
# t value    1.7991275 -0.3067890 -0.005564049
# Pr(>|t|)   0.3229600  0.8104951  0.996457853
```

***Explanation:*** (credits to *@Duncan* from R-help) The caller of `sapply` might ignore the attached `> environment(FO)` `# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>` where the formula was created. This could be the reason why it works with `do.call` and an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

This worked when I tried it. It seems like your use of x in the formula is interfering with the way you'd like the function to behave. Replacing this argument with num generates the results it sounds like you're looking for. This way it ensures that x in the formula refers to the dataset instead of the function argument.

```
sapply(unique(dat$z), function(num) summary(lm(y ~ x, dat, z == num))$coef[1, ])
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort @mcz. I had to completely revise my question, the problem is more tricky.